# getCurrentDate getCurrentTime - constructing a filename with date & time info embedded

Tags: iphone

I am attempting to append the date & time to my filename but I want to modify the default returned values in the string construction:

```
[controller addAttachmentData: logData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"FlightLog%@%@", [self getCurrentDate], [self getCurrentTime]]];
```

Ultimately my filename should be: FlightLog020220130901.txt
Ideally I'd like mmddyyyyhhmm (where hhmm is 24 hour clock format)

Currently the above code is creating a filename like:

> FlightLog2_2_2013 2:23 PM.txt

I'm nervous about the colon in the filename, and I don't like the underscores. Any tips or advice to accomplish this would be very appreciated.

Comment: I figured out the issue I was having; I modified the two methods of getCurrentDate & getCurrentTime to format the string so that the results were put into the correct format. Mission accomplished. If anyone cares to see the code, just ask and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to format a date as a string?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyyHHmmss"];
NSString *fileDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
[dateFormatter release];
[enUSPOSIXLocale release];   

[controller addAttachmentData: logData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"FlightLog%@", fileDate]];
```